# How to place listview inside a scroll view

Tags: android

I have a `RelativeLayout` and below that i have a `ListView`. I have to place these inside a `ScrollView`. Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Comment: Place the `RelativeLayout` view as the header view of the list.

Comment: [Duplicated](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5415011/1050058) , [Duplicated](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4651793/1050058)

Comment: you should not put a listView inside a scrollView. the listView implement its own scrollListener , and it will not responds to events on the scrollView,

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't put a ListView inside a ScrollView because the ListView class implements its own scrolling and it just doesn't receive gestures because they all are handled by the parent ScrollView

Answer (score 0):

`ScrollView` can be set only for a single `Layout`. So place the `widgets` which u want to scroll in a single `layout` as below:

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rltvLyt"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lstView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: i have added that particular layout as the header of my list view and my issue got solved out...

Answer (score 0):

Don't do it. What exactly are you trying to achieve? It had been mentioned here (and everywhere else) this is not a good idea because the scrolling mechanisms get confused as they both want to scroll. Ignoring you however have a listview that is massive then you have missed the major performance gain of using a listview and might swell be using a table layout and add rows.

Comment: Your answer is same as Ram kiran. And if you see this is duplicated, flag question.

Comment: We posted at the same time. Also it might be that what he wants is to use a table layout so I am trying to figure it out because it's possible he is just asking the wrong question in which case we can edit it. I am all for closing questions but sometimes this community is far to happy to do it when all that was wrong is they asked the wrong question  and it looks like a duplicate.